# "Reputation is entirely optional" is not true for editing

Tags: bug, reputation, edits, privileges, help-center

On the `/help/whats-reputation` page ([e.g.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)) it says this:

> The three most important activities on Meta Stack Exchange are [Asking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), [Answering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and [Editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/editing) - none of which require any reputation at all!

However, one actually needs reputation to have full editing privileges, so this statement is not true; without 2,000 reputation and 20,000 reputations, edits to posts and tag wikis, respectively, have to go through a queue.

TL;DR: This page states that editing does not need any reputation at all, when it actually has very major limits without certain privileges. **Can this be changed to clarify, or at least state that editing doesn't need reputation less unequivocally?**

Comment: Disagreed, the page the `Editing` link goes to specifically mentions the bit about edits being reviewed for users <2k.

Comment: There is a balance here between being complete and being concise. I think most people will think your suggesting tips the balance too much. Too exhaustive so it hurts conciseness. I guess people will find out the system after they've edited, and we might want to error on the safe site; if you start off with: "your edit may not be posted" then we might get fewer edits, while the process is not really that painful.

Comment: "*This page states that editing does not need any reputation at all, when it actually has very major limits without certain privileges.*" It's not clear to me why you think both of these statements can't be true. Can you edit without reputation (or even an account at all)? Is editing limited without certain privileges? Do you disagree that the answer to both of those questions is "Yes."?

Answer (score 11):

It's just a simplification, just like 2000 (or 20000) reputation doesn't let you edit locked posts. Or that you only need 100 reputation to freely edit Community Wiki posts. Or the fact that you actually need reputation, 10 to be precise, to *answer* protected questions.

If it's a good edit and the site has a reasonably active review community, there's not much difference; the time between submitting an edit and it becoming publicly visible is negligible to the lifetime of the post itself.